# Find the inverse of $f(x)=3x^3+1$ I get $\sqrt[3]{\frac{x-1}{3}}$ whereas textbook shows answer as $\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{3}}3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am to find the inverse of $f(x)=3x^3+1$. My working:

$$f(x)=3x^3+1$$
$$x=3y^3+1$$
$$x-1=3y^3$$
$$\frac{x-1}{3}=y^3$$
$$f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt[3]\frac{x-1}{3}$$

The solutions section of my textbook says that the answer is  $\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{3}}3$.

How can I arrive at the correct answer? Which step in my working did I go wrong?

Comment: Looks like a typo.

Comment: Looks like a misplaced 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be a typo, a misplaced $3$

Your answer $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{x-1}{3}}$ is correct, as is $\left(\frac{x-1}{3}\right)^{\frac13}$, though you may need to specify using the real cube root rather the principal cube root when $x<1$

If $\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{3}}3$ had really been intended then I suspect it would have been written more tidily as $\sqrt{3({x-1})}$